# MVC Web Application project under MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, routes, nopcommerce

I have 2 distincts MVC Web Applications accessed from:

```
1) product.main-brand.com        (solution landing page)
2) admin.product.main-brand.com  (solution admin landing page)
```

The product is going to change the location from:

```
product.main-brand.com to www.main-brand-com/product
```

And the admin has to change from:

```
admin.product.main-brand.com to www.main-brand-com/product/admin
```

I can't create a Virtual Directory for the admin because www.main-brand-com/product is a controller.

For example, NopCommerce does that, we can go from www.shop.com to www.shop.com/admin and it's changing project and not controller/action. How does he do that?

Comment: You want an entire application to run inside a method? You may want to read up on Areas, but not sure if it will help you

Comment: Hi, thanks! I want to create a URL accessible to the entire application but regarding the naming and logic, it's under the product page

Comment: This is hard to read and decipher. Be much clearer about what you already have cs what you want.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hi, thanks! I have edit the question, please tell me if it's more clear now.

Comment: Do you want ot merge the projects/solutions? Because with 2 separate applications this might be difficult.

Comment: I would prefer not to. I have tried to figure out how nopcommerce does that but I did not found how. They have 2 Project in the same solution and the admin project is accessed by a /admin link in the shop project.

Comment: nopCommerce uses different areas to achieve this. Althought they have url like mystore.com/product and mystore.com/admin/product.

Comment: Hi @Raphael thanks! I have never used Areas so I don't know how to apply them. I saw in NopCommerce code that the admin route register the Area but I can't find how the link works from the shop to /admin. I tried also to create an application in IIS but it use the webconfig file from the website and not from the application inside the website, so I am lost at the moment :(

Comment: I recommend you (like @CamiloTerevinto did) to read up on Areas and take nopCommerce as reference.

Comment: @Patrick I am not sure from where you got the idea that NopCommerce uses a project for landing page and another project for the Admin part. If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/src/NopCommerce.sln) you will see that is **a single application** and not two as you incorrectly state

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Hi, thanks! Maybe I am misunderstanding the concepts. In my Visual Studio NopCommerce solution, I see 2 web projects (Nop.Admin and Nop.Web) in Presentation folder. Admin project has a AdminAreaRegistration.cs file where the admin route is configured. So these are a single application? How can Web project discover the route to Admin in Admin project so? I can't understand this part.

Comment: @Patrick Well, then you don't have the last version of the code or we are talking about different code bases, because in the link I linked in my last comment, there's no `Nop.Admin` project nor a `AdminAreaRegistration` class

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it seems that Admin moved to Web (https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/commit/c7292b45ff9b8101e67ed1ff3f78aee47a0328fb#diff-a2b7e183590d72d3ac9aaaa658be7fda) but I am still using 3.90. Regarding this, the 3.90 structure is the same of mine. Two different Web projects that I need to kind of merge.

Comment: So... do the same they did. Use a single application and look up a tutorial on areas (just search "asp.net mvc areas")

Comment: They changed it for .net core. Before there was a Nop.Admin.csproj inside of Nop.Web/Administration folder. But using areas would be much cleaner (that's why they changed it for .net core)

Comment: @Raphael And do you know if I can achieve that in this case and how? Like nopcommerce 3.90 I also have 2 csproj projects

Comment: I would also suggest to go with areas because areas are easy to use and manage and they have other advantages as well. I have been working on a project which contains two parts, one main website and other is admin site. So i have created areas for that purpose. By using areas, you don't need to create two separate projects. Each area has its own controller, models, views, webconfig etc.

Comment: @Patrick,  Você pode perder muitas vendas!  I strongly suggest you use IIS or web.config to redirect the URL, instead of customizing nop's code base, especially if you have already gone live.  See my answer.

Comment: Try to config your maproute to change controllers default address.

Comment: I am confused why everyone is suggesting areas.  Routing Attributes are the best way to accomplish what he wants with the least amount of impact to his architecture; however, as one person mentioned, if the projects have a relationship with each other, you might want to reconsider your architecture.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some steps to achieve a similar solution like in nopCommerce 3.9

### Create your primary Web Project

Foo.Web

- Properties

  - AssemblyInfo.cs
- Foo.Web.csproj
- Global.asax
- Global.asax.cs
- ...

### Create your admin Web Project inside of your primary Web project

Foo.Web

- **Administration**

  - Properties

    - AssemblyInfo.cs
  - Foo.Admin.csproj
  - ...

*Administration folder must be created using "Add project wizard" or using explorer. Do not create that folder using solution explorer.*

### Remove Global.asax from admin project

You don't need this

### Add an AreaRegistration implementation to your admin project

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName => "Admin";
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute
        (
            name: "AdminDefault",
            url: "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "admin", id = ""},
            namespaces: new[] {"Foo.Admin.Controllers"}
        );
    }
}
```

### Modify Global.asax.cs to register areas

Add this to your project. Make sure it's called before your default routes.

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

> With this, all your controllers inside of Foo.Admin are found by
>   ~/Admin/{controller}/{action} and all your controllers inside Foo.Web
>   are found by ~/{controller}/{action}

Comment: Hi, thanks! Can I add the existing project to the Web project?

Comment: And do you think that this is a good practice trying to achieve something like this?

Comment: TLDR: Look into MVC Areas. They allow you to break up your application into smaller parts. Whenever you create a new area you just need to register its route within your application. (more documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Maybe I would prefer not add the admin project inside the main project.

Comment: You can still work with areas without adding it inside the main project.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 2 distinct MVC web applications I see 2 possible solutions...

a) create an Admin folder inside your main web application and set it as the root of your admin web application i.e. put your whole admin website into the admin folder. I expect this will require some tweaking of web.config of both apps so they can coexist.

b) leave each web application in it's own IIS virtual Application then add rewrite rules in the main web application for the /admin path to the true IIS path and you may need some rewrite rules in the admin app back to the main app if there is expected to be a navigation path to it.

Comment: Yup.  IIS is the the way to go.  See my  answer.

Comment: Hi thanks! But how do you build the URL www.main-brand-com/product/admin with MVC? I know that product is a controller of the main project, but where do I create the admin reference in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you do look into attribute routing.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

This allows you to do this:
   [Route("/product/admin")]

That attribute decorator goes on your controller method after you setup attribute routing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi thanks! But do I have to put one project inside the other?

Comment: You don't have to mix projects at all. Feel free to PM me and I can assist you if you want and get you some more help.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved in asp.net mvc application by using the feature called `Area` (for detail see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas).

Your main application will work for www.main-brand-com. You can add an `Area` for Product to be referred by www.main-brand-com/product and another `Area` called `Admin` to be referred by www.main-brand-com/admin.

You can add an `Area` in asp.net mvc application by right clicking on web application project then selecting `Add` from the quick menu and then select `Area`. It will ask for name of Area to be created. After giving name and clicking `Ok` it will create an Area with that name in Areas folder in your web application project. The newly created Area will have same folder structure like main application like Controller, Model, View etc. folders. It will also create a class (AreaRegistration.cs) for registering the routing details for this Area. The content of this class may look like below code.

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks! I would prefer not add the admin project inside the main project.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, if you're working with an externally maintained platform, you should aim to make as few code changes as possible. You will save yourself the work of merging, testing and deploying your code changes when there's an update. This is especially important if the update is a critical one.

In this particular case, it is best to let IIS to reroute your URLs. It has no code impact and offers a major benefit. Visitors and search using deprecated urls are automatically redirected to newer ones. This is especially important for search engines. If they encounter a 404 error, they will often remove the urls and even the entire site. In other words, *Você pode perder muitas vendas!*

You can reroute your urls in the IIS Manager using the Url Rewrite Module or through web.config files. I recommend web.config files since it can be uploaded and kept together with your project.

For your existing product subdomain site, add the following to the system.webServer section of the site's web.config file:

**product.main-brand.com to www.main-brand-com/product**

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="product.main-brand.com Redirect" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="^\/?$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*product\.main-brand\.com.*" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://www.main-brand-com/product/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite> 
</system.webServer>
```

For your existing admin subdomain site, add the following to the system.webServer section of the site's web.config file:

**admin.product.main-brand.com to www.main-brand-com/product/admin**

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="admin.main-brand.com Redirect" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url="^\/?$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*admin\.product\.main-brand\.com.*" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://www.main-brand-com/product/admin/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

These addition will redirect users to the new URLs.  Refer to the following article for how to setup IIS url rewrite for further information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-global-and-distributed-rewrite-rules

Changing the redirection in IIS is one part, but your application needs to understand how to route the new url scheme internally. Without your app's specific routing code, I can't be of much help. If your application, however, is using subdomain's url parameter and you want to change it, refer to the following article:

https://benjii.me/2015/02/subdomain-routing-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Hi thanks! But how do you build the URL www.main-brand-com/product/admin with MVC? I know that product is a controller of the main project, but where do I create the admin reference in IIS?

Comment: @Patrick  OK.  I understand what you're asking.  Again, you don't want to touch the source code if you can avoid it.  To set the store URL refer to this: http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/Setting+up+Main+Store

Comment: I don't understand your answer. BTW my 2 projects are not nopCommerce, they are two MVC diferent projects.

Comment: Ok. Here is the code:   https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/48110/redirect-admin-login-page.aspx

Comment: I was under the impression you were using nopcommerce.  Is your admin subdomain a separate IIS site?   If so, you will have to add the IIS redirect to both sites. Just make sure you edit it to refer to the particular site referring to. The admin code I just posted is an example of how to do it.  You will need to edit it.  You will have to place it in the appropriate area.

Comment: I forgot to add, nopcommerce admin can be configured in IIS as either a virtual or separate site.

Comment: Is it possible to update your answer based on that case, 2 different websites on IIS like mine? One for the Admin, the other for the Product Landing Page

Comment: I updated my answer. I need to see some routing code to assist any further.